# How to Plot Polar Scalar Fields

Tags: plotting, physics

I am trying to plot the following two equations (where $k_y=k\sin(\theta)$):

$$F(k_y,k_z)=e^{-ika\sin(\theta)}+e^{ika\sin(\theta)}$$
$$F(k_y,k_z)=e^{-ika\sin(\theta)}+e^{ika\sin(\theta)}+e^{-ika\sqrt{2}\sin(\theta)}+e^{ika\sqrt{2}\sin(\theta)}+2$$

I've tried rewriting them as the following, but it hasn't helped me figure it out:

$$F(k_y,k_z)=2\cos(ka\sin(\theta))$$
$$F(k_y,k_z)=2\cos(ka\sin(\theta))+2\cos(ka\sqrt{2}\sin(\theta))+2$$

They are scalar fields, but in terms of polar coordinates. How would I go about plotting these?

*(If it's helpful - these are the equations I have come up with for two separate 2-D diffraction patterns.)*

Comment: please provide them in mma code

Comment: What is kz, k and a? Does F only depend on ky and not on kz?

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Providing Mathematica code that can be copied, pasted, executed and studied is considered the first step at this site as it leads to a focused interaction and a higher probability of problem resolution.

Answer (score 1):

As written this is not really a field but a contour which can be plotted as follows:

```
ka = 10
f[theta_] := 2*Cos[ka*Sin[theta]] + 2*Cos[ka*Sqrt[2]*Sin[theta]] + 2
PolarPlot[f[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

[image]